# How do I correctly pass focus to and from a message box in python 3 in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tkinter

I am attempting to use a message box in Python 3 with Tkinter to solicit a name for a user.  The following stripped down code produces such a message box and correctly passes the values on close, but the message box pops up behind the main window.  If I move the message box out, type something in as a name, and click OK, the main window is updated but hidden behind every other open window.

A friend tried to replicate the issue on a Mac, but the code behaved as expected.

How do I make the message box show up on top with focus at the beginning, and how do I correctly hand focus to the main window when the message box is closed?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter
import tkinter.simpledialog

root = tkinter.Tk()
playerNameVar = tkinter.StringVar()
playerNameVar.set(tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Name", \
    "Name?",parent=root))

playerLabel = tkinter.Label(root,textvariable = playerNameVar)
playerLabel.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"at the beginning"_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"How do I make the message box show up on top with focus at the beginning, and how do I correctly hand focus to the main window when
>   the message box is closed?"*

I don't think you can make the message box show up on top with focus without unwrapping tkinter to its Tcl, you can however easily make the `root` to `lower` itself just before the dialog is shown:

```
root.lower()
```

You can simply call `focus_set` after the lines for calling the dialog line. See below code for complete example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter
import tkinter.simpledialog

root = tkinter.Tk()

root.lower()
playerNameVar = tkinter.StringVar()
playerNameVar.set(tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Name", \
    "Name?",parent=root))
root.focus_set()
#root.tkraise()                 # this is optional

playerLabel = tkinter.Label(root,textvariable = playerNameVar)
playerLabel.grid()

root.mainloop()
```